# TypeError: ElementKeywords.press_keys() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using Selenium Library's press keys for my automation testing

Line of code:

```
self.web.se_lib.press_keys(locator=xpathLocatorHere, keys=1)
```

I need to press any number in my script but it throws an error:

```
TypeError: ElementKeywords.press_keys() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keys'
```

I tried press key only but I believe it's depreciated already and it did not work as well when I tried it

Comment: you may want to get away from Selenium Library, as it's commands are based on the old browser plugin version of Selenium (pre-v2).  Current webdriver command would be send_keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems due to [Press Keys](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Keys)
definition `*keys`, that `keys` is not a named or positional argument. It's due to asterisk `*` sign before definition.

So, it is an aggregated reference to all passed ***unnamed*** values.
You just need to drop the `keys=` part from the question.

For example, to enter random data '111222' there are options:

`press_keys('<locator here>', '111222')`

or

`press_keys('<locator here>', '111', '222')`

etc.